# How to connect whole Native site of Magento in Mobile application?

Tags: link, dynamic, application

Is it possible to connect whole Native Magento site with **Fire-base** ?

- Without creating APIs or connection the default APIs.

Example

```
http://127.0.0.1/Magento23/catalog/product/view/id/2446/
```

- Where Fire-base will create automatically dynamic links for all the
  products

> **NOTE :**  I am aware about APIs and Magento's default APIs but As far I know Fire-base provides option for the same. So Anyone
>   have any idea regarding connecting the native Magento to Firebase